# Android: Hiding LinearLayout and showing other - layout elements mix together

Tags: android, google-maps, android-linearlayout

I have this code:

```
Button go_back_maps = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
go_back_maps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        slide_down Fx = new slide_down();
        setts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Fx.slide_up(Awake.this, setts);
        pick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(Awake.this, pick);

    }
});
```

Basically it's:
Two layouts, Map and MapSettings, when user sets marker in Map layout and clicks continue it hides Map layout with slide up animation, and shows MapSettings layout with slide down animation.

My problem is: When user clicks "Go Back", it opens map again and when user clicks on map to change marker - it reacts to MapSettings layout buttons which makes it impossible to change marker or interact with map.

What's the problem? Those lines are the only lines of code that are responsible for switching between map and mapsettings.

Is there like any way to reload layout or something?

By the way, here is the effects class:

```
    public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v){
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_down);
    if(a != null){
    a.reset();
    if(v != null){
    v.clearAnimation();
    v.startAnimation(a);
    }
    }
    }

    public static void slide_up(Context ctx, View v){
        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_up);
        if(a != null){
        a.reset();
        if(v != null){
        v.clearAnimation();
        v.startAnimation(a);
        }
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Your sentence where you state "My problem is: When user..." is hard for others to follow and understand. Please explain this in more detail. Better to provide too much detail and state the obvious, than not provide enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the problem is a little hard to follow and understand.

However regarding your question:

> "Is there like any way to reload layout or something?"

Here's a few things to consider:

1) You can set the the layout for an activity with `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`, but keep in mind that calling `setContentView()` multiple times in an activity has a number of pitfalls that can trip you up. Any references you are holding to views in the previous layout will need to be reset, and for safety you should entirely remove all existing views before inflating the new one.

2) You can Invalidate a layout, causing it to be drawn again.

```
ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.my_layout);
vg.invalidate();
```